# Object both exists and doesn't exist in an R browser() session

Tags: r, browser, exists

I've been having this problem for the last couple of years with newer versions of R. Here I'm using 3.1.3. (I don't use the newest versions because some of the packages I use are not supported by them.)

An object is present in the function and I can use it in the browser(), but then if I send a block of script to the R console, it doesn't recognize the object. If I call the function without invoking the browser(), the function usually works as expected without throwing an error message.

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
b <- c(12,34,56,42,78)
dframe <- data.frame(a,b)

dummy <- function(){
 browser()
  fit <- lm(b ~ a ,dframe)
  p.val <-  summary(fit)$coef[8]
  if (p.val <0.05) {
    cat("Significant \n")
  }else{  
   cat("Not significant \n")
  }
}

dummy()
```

If I then send all of the above to the console, the browser() opens:

> source(file('clipboard'))
>
> Called from: dummy()
>
> Browse[1]>   fit <- lm(b ~ a ,dframe)
>
> Browse[1]>   p.val <-  summary(fit)$coef[8]
>
> Browse[1]> summary(fit)
>
> Browse[1]> p.val
>
> [1] 0.03815541
>
> Browse[1]> p.val <0.05
>
> [1] TRUE

Now I send the if{}else{} function to the console as a block of text.

> Browse[1]> source(file('clipboard'))
>
> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'p.val' not found   # why ?
>
> Browse[1]> exists("p.val")
>
> [1] TRUE
>
> Browse[1]>   if (p.val <0.05) {  # step through the if{}else{} line by line
>
> - cat("Significant \n")
> - }else{
> - cat("Not significant \n")
> - }
>
> debug at #2: cat("Significant \n")      #why ?
>
> Browse[3]>

So why doesn't my object "p.val" exist in the browser() session, when it clearly does?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you want

```
source(file="clipboard", local=TRUE)
```

The `p.val` is only defined at the local scope. By default `source()` calls things in the user's global scope, not the local function scope.

Comment: Thanks! But why does it return "debug at #2..."?

Comment: What do you mean, "why"? That's just telling you the line number that it's currently debugging Because you pasted in a new expression, the next line to continue debugging is that second line. I'm not sure what you were expecting.

Comment: Okay, thanks again. I don't think older versions of R did that. I guess I need to update my skills.

Comment: I was expecting it to execute because the if() condition was met.